# 'git pull' executing in SSH, but not in github post-receive script

Tags: php, git, ssh, github, shell-exec

I am trying to setup github to websever deployment automation. I've got everything working except the most important bit. I have a file @ mydomain.com/github.php that looks like this:

```
<?php
`git pull`;
?>
```

and this is the post-receive URL for my github repo. Github is posting to it successfuly, but the shell command is not running. When I try SSHing into my server, and running the script directly:

```
php github.php
```

it works just fine and changed files are pulled succesfully

```
From git://github.com/user/Repo
   7e3176d..f889c14  master     -> origin/master
```

but when accessing the page in my browser or when github POSTs to it - the shell command is not executed. There is no error - just an empty result. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I've never seen that PHP syntax before

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php I just learned about it the other day myself :)

Comment: try <?php echo ``git pull`` ?>

Comment: @KubaW did you mean to put git pull inside backticks?

Comment: @Yev: yep, it will output the execution results

Comment: @zerkms Sorry I wasn't clear in the original question, but I already tried this. That's what I meant by: "There is no error - just an empty result."

Comment: @Yev: any comments to my answer?

Comment: how about `echo git pull 2>&1;` (just put backticks on correct place) and updated my answer

Comment: @zerkms looks like we're making some headway! When I tried that I got the following response: "error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied"

Comment: @Yev: so the problem is with permissions ;-) Try to see `echo whoami;` (with backticks) and see the permissions for the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7927/discussion-between-yev-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 possible issues:

1. Permissions - most likely your webserver user doesn't have necessary
2. Work directory. Double check that your shell command is being executed in correct path (`getcwd()`)

**UPD**

Git outputs the error messages to stderr, so to see the real error message you need

```
echo `git pull 2>&1`;
```

Comment: 1. I am doing this on one of the subaccounts of my VPS. I have full control to go in and make the nessecary changes to permissions, but unfortuantely I'm not sure how/where I would do this. Could you give me some guidance how I would be able to check and set the appropriate permissions?

2. The current working directory is correct.

Comment: "error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied" is the error I am receiving.